# Create link many table to one table

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I want to implement translation into different languages of some data from different tables. Conditionally I have a menu table and a description table, I create two tables 1 with locale:

```
public class Language : BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Culture { get; set; }
}
```

And actually with translations

```
public class LanguageResource : BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot
{
   public Guid ParentUid { get; set; }
   public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Where ParentUid is the Uid in the Menu that I would like to map to this table and get the data.

```
public class Menu : BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public Guid Uid { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<LanguageResource> languageResources { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Priority { get; set; }
}
```

But also in ParentUid, I would like to put the Uid of another table, so as not to create a million tables with translations for each.

Can you tell me how this can be further implemented? I can't properly set up a table link through CodeFirst

Comment: First off, if you're using entity-framework make your collections an `ICollection`, instead of an `IEnumerable`, also make them `virtual`. Why would you want to store the foreign `ID` in the object when you're using entity-framework though? That is kind of missing the point of the entity framework. You want to have the object as a property, not the id. Is there a recursion issue you are running into - thus you want to store the id, not the object?

Comment: @speyck Why I need to use ICollection? This is a virtual, it is an old example. I need create table for translation to another language, and this solution could help me

Comment: I don't really understand what you need. Has this question anything to do with .net or is it a general question on how you should shape your database tables?

Comment: @speyck yep it's question "how I can create link many table to one table use CodeFirst?" because I don't understand how create this link in Fluent. For example I did it `builder.Entity<Category>().HasAlternateKey(x => x.Uid);` but I have a problem...

Comment: now I understand. so in your `LanguageResource` you want the `Guid` of a parent `LanguageResource` right? did you try instead of using the `Guid` directly using a `LanguageReference` object? let me know what happens.

Comment: @speyck I would like each table I need to have a translation of the text, and if the table has a UID (foreign key) and the resource refers to this UID through ParentUID, then I could get the translation I need from Menu.Resource.Language. ParentUid have Menu's Uid for example